# Distinguish two modal windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have applied a class **modal-link** on my url like so:

```
<a href="form.php" class="modal-link"></a>
```

This will open up my *form.php* on a modal(popup) window, with this code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.modal-link').click(function(event)
    {
        // Declare vars
        var url, openModal;

        // Prevent link opening
        event.preventDefault();

        // Store url
        url = this.href;

        // Function to open modal
        openModal = function()
        {
            $.modal({
                title: 'My title',
                maxWidth: 500,
                url: url,
                loadingMessage: 'Loading...',
                buttons: {
                    'Close': function(win) { win.closeModal(); },
                    'Open new modal': openModal
                }

            });
        };

        // Open first modal
        openModal();
    });
});
</script>
```

On this modal window as you can see there is a button called "Open new modal", this button will open a new modal window containing the same *form.php* file while the first modal window is still being visible.

If I go ahead and submit the form on my first modal window it will not work since the two modals (containing the same form.php) seems to collide with each other.

Submitting my form works if I only have one modal window open.

Is there a way to make each modal unique so that I can submit the form on my first modal window without colliding or interfering with the second modal window?

A way to distinguish the two modal windows?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what is `$.modal`? I tried searching and it I couldn't find anything that made that clear. Is it a plugin that you're using?

Also can you clarify whether the form submit causes a page load or is it ajax based? If it is ajax based, some event or variables could be clashing.

I generally keep the console on chrome open when I'm debugging Javascript, makes debugging easier generally.